# Parameters start_id and end_id when calling http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=ft&tsp=

Tags: osm2po

How do I pass parameters start_id and end_id when calling  http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=ft&tsp=1,2,3,4,5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TSP usually expects source=target. The parameters are fully explained on the osm2po-WebPage (under help->server). Nevertheless, what you need is a CSV of VertexIds you are going to visit. The first id is your source and the last one the target. The initial order of in between ids is arbitrary. osm2po even allows source and target to be different.